# Should base trim have a gap between it and laminate flooring?

Tags: flooring, trim, baseboard, laminate

Is it correct that when adding baseboard trim on the laminate floor, it is recommended to have a 1-2mm gap between the trim and the laminate planks? So that it should not be tight to it.

I thought that the space must be maintained only at the perimeter of room.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: The reason I was asking is that I watched youtube video where the guye was saying that it is important to keep the gap between the base trim and the laminate floor since the laminate tends to extend and contract. And it sounded strange to me, because I'm only aware that the laminate can extend/contract in length, not in height.

Comment: I'd guess that he misspoke or that you misunderstood. Or he was plain wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I've never encountered a flooring that recommended that, and if one did I wouldn't install it (or I'd deny that request). It would look odd.

Comment: With some subfloors or underlayment the base has inherent gaps anyway. With gaps that are too large I typically scribe and trim off the bottom of the base to keep it tight. That is if I can't get it to conform by pushing it down.